# Does Hustle Affect Moves that Bypass Accuracy

Tags: pokemon-series

The ability Hustle boosts the attack stat by 50% but reduces the accuracy of physical moves 20%.

So what happens to physical attacks that 'always hit' like aerial ace? Do they receive the boost and do they become capable of missing?

Answer (score 9):

*[Aerial Ace](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Aerial_Ace_(move))* and other 'always hit' moves are considered as not having an accuracy modifier, and are therefore unaffected by changes to accuracy or evasion from any sources, including Hustle. This means that Hustle will boost their power only: accuracy for these moves will be unaffected.

Note that 'always hit' moves are denoted in-game as 'Accuracy: --':

[image: Aerial Ace stats]

If a move has 'Accuracy: 100%', then it will be affected by the Accuracy changes from Hustle. [Pound](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pound_(move)) for example:

[image: Pound Stats]

Answer (score 3):

All physical moves gain the 50% bonus, including moves that always hit. Since they always hit, a 20% decrease in accuracy will have no effect.